# I am having error invalid syntax in my python code

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to add multiple inner function in my code. But I am not able to add it properly and also it is giving me a syntax error. Here I am trying to run my python script when I click a button and it will take input from a textfield and then run my script which has multiple functions. Is this the right way to add inner functions or is there another way to do this?

**ERROR**
File "server.py", line 17``
pass = request.form['typed']here
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6Mg2.png

from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect
app= Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')`enter code here`
def my_home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/<string:page_name>')
def html_page(page_name):
    return render_template(page_name)

import hashlib
import sys
import requests
@app.route('/send',methods =['POST'])
def send():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pass = request.form['typed']
        
    def request_api_data(query_char)
            res = requests.get(url)
            if res.status_code != 200:
                raise RuntimeError(f'Error fetching: {res.status_code}, check the api and try again')
                return res
```

Answer (score 1):

`pass` is a statement and cannot be used as a variable name.

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#pass-statements

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect
app= Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')`enter code here`
def my_home():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/<string:page_name>')
def html_page(page_name):
    return render_template(page_name)

import hashlib
import sys
import requests
@app.route('/send',methods =['POST'])
def send():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # pass = request.form['typed']
        my_pass = request.form['typed']  # <- this should work.
        
    def request_api_data(query_char)
            res = requests.get(url)
            if res.status_code != 200:
                raise RuntimeError(f'Error fetching: {res.status_code}, check the api and try again')
                return res
```